# Вывод свойств объекта на экран

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести название всех животных которые находятся в первой клетке, я попытался сделать циклом:

```
for (Object o : oneCell.getAnimal()) {
    System.out.println(o);

}
```

Но, я не могу переменную о сделать Animal и вызвать метод .getName()

```
for(Animal o: oneCell.getAnimal()) {
    System.out.println(o.getName())
}
```

Примерно так

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

 static class Zoo {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList newCell = new ArrayList();
    private Cell cell;
    Animal t_anim;

    public Zoo(String Name) {
        name = Name;

    }

    public void addCell(Cell cell) {
        newCell.add(cell);
    }

    public void removeCell(Cell cell) {
        newCell.remove(cell);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public Animal findName(String name) {
       // for (Object t_cell : newCell) {
            ArrayList t_animList = Cell.getAnimalList();
            for (Object t_anim : t_animList) {
                if (Animal.getName() == name)
                    return (Animal) t_anim;
            }

       // }
        return null;
    }

    static class Cell {
        private int number;
        private int size;
        private int maxQuantityAnimal; // Максимальное кол-во животных
        private int currentQuantityAnimal; // Текущее кол-во животных
        private Animal animal;

        public Cell(int Number, int Size, int MaxQuantityAnimal, int CurrentQuantityAnimal) {
            number = Number;
            size = Size;
            maxQuantityAnimal = MaxQuantityAnimal;
            currentQuantityAnimal = CurrentQuantityAnimal;
        }


        private static ArrayList newAnimal = new ArrayList();

        public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
            newAnimal.add(animal);
        }

        public void removeAnimal(Animal animal) {
            newAnimal.remove(animal);
        }

        public ArrayList getAnimal() {
            return newAnimal;
        }

        public Animal GetAnimal() {

            return animal;
        }

        public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
            this.animal = animal;
        }

        public static ArrayList getAnimalList() {
            return newAnimal;
        }
    }

     static class Animal {
        private static String name;
        private static Boolean predator;
        private Cell cell;
        private Zoo zoo;
        private ArrayList newCell = new ArrayList();

        public Animal(String Name, Boolean Predator) {
            name = Name;
            predator = Predator;
        }
        
        public Cell getCell() {
            return cell;
        }

        public void setCell(Cell cell) {
            this.cell = cell;
        }

        public static String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String newNme) {
            name = newNme;
        }

        public static Boolean getPredator() {
            return predator;
        }

        public void setPredator(Boolean newPredator) {
            predator = newPredator;
        }

    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Zoo newZoo = new Zoo("NSK");
    Zoo.Cell oneCell = new Zoo.Cell(5, 60, 10, 1);
    Zoo.Cell twoCell = new Zoo.Cell(10, 80, 20, 2);
    Zoo.Animal oneAnimal = new Zoo.Animal("Тигр", true);
    Zoo.Animal twoAnimal = new Zoo.Animal("Лев", false);
    Zoo.Animal threeAnimal = new Zoo.Animal("Пантера", false);
    newZoo.addCell(oneCell);
    newZoo.addCell(twoCell);
    oneCell.addAnimal(oneAnimal);
    oneCell.addAnimal(twoAnimal);
    twoCell.addAnimal(threeAnimal);

    for (Object o : oneCell.getAnimal()) {
        System.out.println(o);

    }
   // System.out.println(Zoo.Animal.getName());

    Zoo.Animal foundAnimal = newZoo.findName("Тигр");
    System.out.println(foundAnimal.getPredator());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой вам совет. Раскидайте все классы в отдельные файлы без лишней вложенности и скорректируйте код. Вот так все работает . Мейби опечатался где, поправите:

```
public class Animal {
private  String name;
private  Boolean predator;
private Cell cell;
private Zoo zoo;
private ArrayList newCell = new ArrayList();

public Animal(String Name, Boolean Predator) {
    name = Name;
    predator = Predator;
}

public Cell getCell() {
    return cell;
}

public void setCell(Cell cell) {
    this.cell = cell;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String newNme) {
    name = newNme;
}

public Boolean getPredator() {
    return predator;
}

public void setPredator(Boolean newPredator) {
    predator = newPredator;
}

}

public class Cell {
private int number;
private int size;
private int maxQuantityAnimal; // Максимальное кол-во животных
private int currentQuantityAnimal; // Текущее кол-во животных
private Animal animal;

public Cell(int Number, int Size, int MaxQuantityAnimal, int CurrentQuantityAnimal) {
    number = Number;
    size = Size;
    maxQuantityAnimal = MaxQuantityAnimal;
    currentQuantityAnimal = CurrentQuantityAnimal;
}


private ArrayList<Animal> newAnimal = new ArrayList();

public void addAnimal(Animal animal) {
    newAnimal.add(animal);
}

public void removeAnimal(Animal animal) {
    newAnimal.remove(animal);
}

public ArrayList<Animal> getAnimal() {
    return newAnimal;
}

public Animal GetAnimal() {

    return animal;
}

public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
    this.animal = animal;
}

public  ArrayList<Animal> getAnimalList() {
    return newAnimal;
}
}

public class Zoo {
private String name;
private ArrayList<Cell> newCell = new ArrayList();

public Zoo(String Name) {
    name = Name;
}

public void addCell(Cell cell) {
    newCell.add(cell);
}

public void removeCell(Cell cell) {
    newCell.remove(cell);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

 public Animal findName(String name, Cell cell) {
    ArrayList<Animal> t_animList = cell.getAnimalList();
    for (Animal t_anim : t_animList) {
        if (t_anim.getName().equals(name))
            return t_anim;
    }

    return null;
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Zoo newZoo = new Zoo("NSK");

    Cell oneCell = new Cell(5, 60, 10, 1);
    Cell twoCell = new Cell(10, 80, 20, 2);

    Animal oneAnimal = new Animal("Тигр", true);
    Animal twoAnimal = new Animal("Лев", false);
    Animal threeAnimal = new Animal("Пантера", false);

    oneCell.addAnimal(oneAnimal);
    oneCell.addAnimal(twoAnimal);
    twoCell.addAnimal(threeAnimal);

    newZoo.addCell(oneCell);
    newZoo.addCell(twoCell);


    for (Animal o : oneCell.getAnimal()) {
       System.out.println(o.getName();)
    }

     Animal foundAnimal = newZoo.findName("Тигр", oneCell);
    System.out.println(foundAnimal.getPredator());

 
}
}
```

Comment: Отредактировал, а дальше, что с этим делать, не пойму)

Comment: А в чем проблема осталась? По прежнему переменная "о"  не хочет быть Animal?

Comment: А нет, все норм, я затупил)
Только почему, я в этой клетке вижу трех Пантер.
А должен увидеть Тигра и Льва

Comment: @Saintka скинул код должно работать

Comment: Все супер) спасибо

Comment: @Saintka пометьте как решение плз

Comment: смотри у меня там функция findName 
public Animal findName(String name) {
       // for (Object t_cell : newCell) {
            ArrayList t_animList = Cell.getAnimalList();
            for (Object t_anim : t_animList) {
                if (Animal.getName() == name)
                    return (Animal) t_anim;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

ее можно реанимировать?

Comment: Сейчас посмотрим

Comment: @Saintka добавил. В качестве второго параметра передавайте клетку в которой нужно искать

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое)